# Blueimp File Upload : How not to list files in subfolders?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

For each user I create a main folder we call **User**. In this folder, you've got all files the user has uploaded (and the auto-created subfolder called **thumbnails**). On the backoffice side, I want to upload quotes and invoices in separates folders we'll call **quotes** and **invoices**.

Here is the tree :

```
User
 |_ file_01.jpg
 |_ file_02.jpg
 |_ file_03.jpg
 |_ file_04.jpg
 |_ thumbnails
 |   |_ file_01.jpg
 |   |_ file_02.jpg
 |   |_ file_03.jpg
 |   |_ file_04.jpg
 |
 |_ quotes
 |   |_ myquote.pdf
 |
 |_ invoices
     |_ myinvoice.pdf
```

I want to hide files contained in folders **quotes** and **invoices** (that are automatically created by blueimp script) without an .htaccess file, each time I want to list the **User** folder content through blueimp script.

Is there an option in blueimp which could enable/disable listing of subfolders files for instance ?

That makes sense ?

Comment: "*without an .htaccess file*" - Why?

Comment: Because I simply don't want to create an htaccess file each time I create a new directory in each User folder. It might be done with an option through the blueimp script I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a single `.htaccess` file to deny access from just the two directories (quotes and invoices).

This means 1 `.htaccess` file in the directory `User`.

```
RewriteRule ^(quotes/|invoices/) - [F,L,NC]
```

- `F` - Using the `[F]` flag causes the server to return a 403 Forbidden status code to the client. While the same behavior can be accomplished using the Deny directive, this allows more flexibility in assigning a Forbidden status.
- `L` - The `[L]` flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed.
- `NC` - Use of the `[NC]` flag causes the RewriteRule to be matched in a case-insensitive manner

See the Apache documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

<sup>**Footnote:** If you want them hidden, then you could have an `index.html` file in your `User` directory and return a `403` (?) - or move the directories you want to hide out of the web root.</sup>

Comment: In fact, I don't want to "deny" access to theses directories, I just want the user (just him) doesn't see them when he's in front of his file upload/download form. I thought it was possible to simply hide specific directories through fileupload ajax call. So, I finally found another way to do what I needed...

Comment: Hey @XavierC., I'm in the same situation here, how did you managed to hide the subfolders from user's view?

Comment: @DimasPante To hide the subfolders from the users view, add `Options -Indexes` into your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Yeah, actually my doubt is the same as Xavier's, but many thanks anyway :)